# Not able to find element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

[screenshot of error I m facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OhxY.png)

```
searchbox=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')
searchbox.send_Keys("abc")
```

above line is showing error
it is saying `'list' object has no attribute 'send_Keys'`.
I have seen this kind of question on stack over flow but the solution is not helping me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
searchbox = driver.find_element_by_id("search")
```

You can replace find_element_by_... with a method of your choice:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: The id searchbox can be used multiple times. It might be looking at the first instance of when it is used. Try defining it more specifically

Answer (score 0):

How did you get searchbox variable?

Did you use `driver.find_element_by_xpath` or `driver.find_elements_by_xpath`?

I guess that you used `find_elements_by_xpath`. If you use `find_elements_by_xpath`, you can get a list of web elements.

In order to get a web element, you should use `find_element_by_xpath`.

Comment: Did you still get a same error "'list' object has no attribute"?